Why does my `updateCartUIWithNewData` function fail to update cart items correctly in vanilla JavaScript?
I'm working on an e-commerce website and trying to update the shopping cart UI when the cart data changes. I have a function updateCartUIWithNewData that is supposed to handle this, but it doesn't work as expected.
Here is the non-working version of my updateCartUIWithNewData function. The goal of this function is to update the shopping cart UI based on the provided cart data.
function updateCartUIWithNewData(cart) {
  console.log("Updating cart UI with cart data:", cart);
  
  // Clear the existing cart UI
  itemContainer.innerHTML = '';

  // Re-render the cart items
  cart.items.forEach(item => {
    console.log("Processing cart item:", item); // Log each item in the cart
    const existingCartItem = findExistingCartItem(item.product.toString());
    updateCartUI(existingCartItem, item.product, item.price, item.quantity);
  });

  // Update the cart count
  updateTheCartCount();
}

Expected Behavior: The function should fetch the details for each product in the cart and update the UI accordingly.
Actual Behavior: The function runs without errors, but the UI doesn't update as expected. The product details like name, price, and size are missing in the cart.
Additional Context:

itemContainer is a reference to the container element holding the cart items.
findExistingCartItem is a function that finds a cart item by product ID.
updateCartUI is a function that updates the cart item UI.
updateTheCartCount is a function that updates the cart item count displayed to the user.

Here are simplified versions of these functions for reference:
function findExistingCartItem(productId) {
  return itemContainer.querySelector(`.item[data-product-id="${productId}"]`);
}

function updateCartUI(existingCartItem, productToAdd, updatedPrice, quantity) {
  const templateElement = getTemplateElement();
  if (!templateElement) return;

  const templateContent = getTemplateContent(templateElement);
  if (!templateContent) return;

  if (existingCartItem) {
    updateExistingCartItem(existingCartItem, updatedPrice);
  } else {
    addNewItemToCart(templateContent, productToAdd, updatedPrice, quantity);
  }

  updateTheCartCount();
}

I've tried adding console logs to trace the execution and verify that the function is called with the correct data. However, the UI still doesn't update as expected. I suspect that the issue might be related to how I'm fetching product details
I've uploaded the full project to GitHub for better context. You can find it here:
https://github.com/datogoco/Namo
https://github.com/datogoco/Namo
To reproduce the issue:

Clone the repository.
Follow the setup instructions in the README.
Create a config.env file based on the config.env.example file and fill in the required values.
Try to add an item to the cart and observe the console logs and UI behavior.

Could someone help me understand why the updateCartUIWithNewData function isn't updating the cart UI correctly and suggest a solution to fix this issue? Any guidance on properly handling asynchronous operations in this context would be greatly appreciated.

FYI, I don't see any asynchronous activity here.

If you log the newItem in addNewItemToCart, does it appear correct?  BTW, addNewItemToCart and addItemToCartUI are practically identical.  You might consider refactoring that.
